# Flask save request files cannot handle two consequent images

Tags: android, python, android-asynctask, flask

I am sending two images each from different process using AsyncTask in Android to my Flask backend where I am saving these images like this

```
if allowed_file(filename):
    try:
        request.files['image'].save(folder)
    except Exception as e:
        abort(400, message="Couldn't save image!")
    # save to the database
    try:
        image = Image(
            fk_event=event_id,
            folder=folder),
            description=args['description']
        )

        db.session.add(image)
        db.session.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        abort(400, message="Couldn't save image to the database!")

    return image, 200
```

If I send just one single image, everything is OK, but when I am saving two images one immediately after another I am getting **400: Couldn't save image!**. If I put delay between these processes like 1 sec, it's OK again but I this isn't the solution as many users might save files at once.

Do you have any idea where is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll get a more meaningful debug experience if you actually log or output your exceptions.

I would do the following modification

```
try:
    request.files['image'].save(folder)
except Exception as e:
    abort(400, message="Couldn't save image! %s" % e)
```

Comment: I've tried this but the problem is that error string is "400: Bad request" which isn't helpful